# Async.Parallel doesn't run list |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.Start?

Tags: f#

I have the following code to test https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpx.Async/blob/master/src/FSharpx.Async/BlockingQueueAgent.fs

However, it prints `Done 0` at the end. It seems the `[ enqueue(); enqueue(); enqueue() ]` is not run?

```
let ag = new BlockingQueueAgent<int option>(500)

let enqueue() = async { for i = 0 to 1000 do ag.Add (Some i) }

[ enqueue(); enqueue(); enqueue() ] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore |> Async.Start

ag.Add None

let mutable x = 0

let rec dequeue() =
    async {
        let! m = ag.AsyncGet()
        match m with
        | Some v ->
            x <- x + v
            return! dequeue()
        | None -> 
            printfn "Done %d" x
    }

dequeue() |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have a race condition: `ag.Add None` happens before the `enqueue` copies even have a chance to run, because you're starting them on a background thread with `Async.Start`. In order to maintain the correct order of operations, make them all part of a single async workflow:

```
let enqueueAll = async {
    do! [ enqueue(); enqueue(); enqueue() ] |> Async.Parallel |> Async.Ignore
    ag.Add None
}

Async.Start enqueueAll
```

This way, `ag.Add None` won't be executed until `Async.Parallel` finishes, which will happen after all copies of `enqueue()` are done.